# Residuals and the law of large numbers

Tags: residuals, law-of-large-numbers

Can I apply the law of large numbers (LLN) to $ê$ (the observed residuals)? For example, can I use LLN for ($1/n)∑ê$ and say that converge to $E[e]$ (where $e$ is the true error)?

I think that I can't do it because the residual is not a random variable.  Could you help me to understand that?

Comment: I reopened, but this is still slightly unclear. I assume you mean $(1/n)∑ê$, not $1/(n∑ê)$, but it is ambiguous since you didn't use mathjax to write up the mathematical expressions. Can you at least use parentheses to clarify this?

Comment: You have absolutely reason, I knew today about mathjax. The other times that I asked about what use for write it no one answered me

Comment: Please confirm what you mean by adding parentheses. Regarding how to use mathjax generally, see: [Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1604/7290).

Comment: You can find some ideas [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245327/weak-law-of-large-numbers-for-dependent-random-variables-with-bounded-covariance). If you try to apply those ideas, you will find that you need to specify *which residuals* (there are multiple kinds) from *which kind of model*.

Comment: A residual typically *is* a random variable because it's a function of random variables.  The reason you cannot apply the usual laws of large numbers directly is because the residuals usually are not independent.  There are such laws for dependent variables, but they are based on specific assumptions about the dependence and the sequence of variables.  That brings us back to the implicit request for more information about your situation made by @kjetilbhalvorsen.